# Ho to change existing MD5 checksum value to make it different from previous value

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have loaded some data from source to target through powercenter mapping , in this mapping update happens when src md5<>tgt md5 c so what happend is through unconnected like we are returning  1 column whose data type is String  but in target that column we are loading it as INT so in my latest code fix in target level i changed the column data type to decimal and few more logic change in expression , But the data which is already loaded in target will not update with the latest change because we are updating only when checksum is <> between src and target.

so in this case i want to change my md5checksum in target so that checksum will be different from src and that column will update. Because now since all data is loaded from src to target so checksum is same and it is not updating latest column change with correct value it works only after truncating the target table but in prod we can not truncate table so we have to reprocess history data

What approach should I go for , how can I change directly md5 value in target table … if I want to update the table also then what should I approach and how can it will not hamper the production data

I have to update target md5 checksum value but not exactly sure what value I should put or how exactly I can make that value different from src md5 value

Comment: I'm sorry, but your post is really hard to understand. Please put some more effort to describe the current implementation, the issue and what have you tried so far. Trying to guess I'd say you need to calculate the MD5 checksum using the source data and compare the value aginst target. There should be no need to update data in the target.